# Backbone - reading template data from DOM in View

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to figure out the best way for a backbone view to read template data.  I'm using underscore templates.

I have a template defined in a script block on the page:

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
        This is my template
</script>
```

However, I'm having trouble reading in the template in certain parts of the view (I assume this is somethin g to do with el scoping).  For example:

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'someClassName',

    t1 : $('#template').html(),

    initialize: function() {

        var t1 = this.t1;
        var t2 = $('#template').html();

        ...
    },
    ...
```

`t1` contains the correct template html, while `t2` is null.

**Why is this? and Where is the correct place in the view to read in this template from the DOM?**

Comment: I always read the template in during the render function. Can you make a fiddle? Have you tried putting a breakpoint in initialize and running the jQuery HTML method manually to see the results?

Comment: If I read `$('#template').html()` in `render()` I get null/not defined :(

Comment: What about if you set a breakpoint in the script on the initialize method (you can do this by putting in a `debugger;` command in the code or manually adding it other scripts tab in firebug/webkit). This will allow you to see the state of the execution context at run time.

Comment: @tkone - any suggestions regarding what I should be checking, regarding the context at this point?  I don't really know what to check to know why the jquery selector isn't working...

Comment: Have you checked it in the debugger?  I've asked that several times and haven't heard you answer that yet.

Comment: @tkone - Yes, I have tried the debugger. My point is, I'm not sure what I should be checking there to see what's going on with the jquery selector (or what the context of the select is).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9152/discussion-between-tkone-and-upthecreek)

Comment: That's interesting as I'm having the opposite issue occurring.  The property definition of the template within the view object is coming up as null, while within my initialize it is actually finding the html template.  Will be interested in seeing what your solution is.

Comment: @aztechy - I've kind of abandonded this for now, will let you know if I dig into it again.  What DTD are you using? - I remember deciding that this was related to the fact I was using HTML5

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to figure out the best way for a backbone view to read template data. I'm using underscore templates.

To answer that particular part of your question. May I suggest using a plugin in requirejs?

Since you run an app.js, I guess maybe you are using requirejs. I'm testing my luck here. My guess could be totally wrong. But in the case that you are, why not try to use the text! plugin from requirejs that reads in a file as string (your template) like so?

```
define(
['text!templates/template.html'], function(myTemplate){
});
```

So far, this works beautifully as far as my template goes. Never ran into a single problem with this method.

You'll be able to find this under [here](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) in the "Modularizing a Backbone View" section

Comment: Using require.js or curl.js to load templates in as dependencies is so much cleaner and more fun to develop with. +1 for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The value of an object literal is evaluated immediately, so your jQuery selector for the template is returning empty. You need to wait until the DOM is ready to select the template.

See this article for more information:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it's the one outside of the function that works. In the initialise function (deferred execution presumably) I can't read the DOM element properly.

Comment: Yeah thats the perplexing part. First bug that bit me when I started using backbone was creating my view before the DOM was ready and trying to set the template there. Hence setting it in render!

Comment: and also making sure you're not creating a view instance before the DOM is ready. even if you have the selector in `render`, if you have a view instance before the DOM is ready, you won't get anything.

Comment: @DerickBailey all instantiation is done through an 'app' view, which itself is instantiated in a `$(document).ready(function() {` so I don't think it's that :(

Comment: the only other answer i could possibly see, based on what you've said, is that the "#template" doesn't exist in the page when you run the selector... is something deleting or otherwise removing it?

Comment: Hmm, nothing like that is happening to me knowledge.  I'll try to set up a jsfiddle to replicate.